Characterization of Group homomorphisms from $(\mathbb{Q}^*,\cdot)$ to $(\mathbb{Q},+)$.
Consider the following fact:

There does not exist any nontrivial group homomorphism from $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ to $(\mathbb{Q}^*,\cdot)$.

My question:
Is it also true that there does not exist any nontrivial group homomorphism from $(\mathbb{Q}^*,\cdot)$ to $(\mathbb{Q},+)$?
If it is not true then how can we find all those nontrivial homomorphisms?

I tried to prove that there does not exist any nontrivial homomorphism by way of contradiction but I was unable to do so because after fixing the image of $1$, all rational numbers can not be written  as the product of $1$ so I was unable to find the homomorphism.
Also I can not find any specific nontrivial homomorphism.
Kindly someone help me. Thank you.

The question in title can be answered in the positive by the same method as this answer of mine.

The group $(\mathbb Q^*,\cdot)$ is actually much "simpler" (in certain sense) than $(\mathbb Q,+)$. Note that any rational number can be represented as
$$\pm p_1^{n_1}\cdot p_2^{n_2}\cdot p_3^{n_3} \cdots$$
for some prime numbers $p_k$ and some integers $n_k$, and this representation is unique. Multiplication boils down to adding the powers $n_k$ corresponding to the same prime number $p_k$, and multiplying the signs.
Algebraically this means that we have a group isomorphism
$$(\mathbb Q^*,\cdot) \cong (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)\oplus\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z\oplus\cdots$$
where the $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ term is the sign, and each $\mathbb Z$ term corresponds to some prime number.
A homomorphism from a sum of groups is completely defined by homomorphisms from the summands. A homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ is defined by the image of 1, which can be any element in the codomain.
Finally, a homomorphism from $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ has to map 1 to some rational number $q$ such that $q+q=0$, meaning $q=0$.
Combining all this, any homomorphism $\varphi : (\mathbb Q^*,\cdot)\rightarrow (\mathbb Q, +)\,$  corresponds to an infinite sequence of completely arbitrary rational numbers $(q_1,q_2,q_3,\dots)$, and is defined by
$$\varphi(-1) = 0$$
$$\varphi(p_i) = q_i$$
where $p_i$ is the sequence of all prime numbers $(2,3,5,7,\dots)$.
Explicitly,
$$\varphi(\pm p_1^{n_1}\cdot p_2^{n_2}\cdot p_3^{n_3} \cdots) = n_1 q_1 + n_2 q_2 + n_3 q_3 + \dots$$


Is it also true that there does not exist any nontrivial group homomorphism from $(\mathbb{Q}^*,\cdot)$ to $(\mathbb{Q},+)$?

There are lots of such homomorphisms. First of all note that every rational number can be uniquely written as
$$\pm 1\cdot p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}$$
where each $p_i$ is a prime number and $\alpha_i\in\mathbb{Z}$. It is a straightforward consequence that we have the following group isomorphism:
$$\mathbb{Q}^*\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\bigoplus_{p\in{\rm Primes}}\mathbb{Z}$$
So when considering a $\mathbb{Q}^*\to\mathbb{Q}$ homomorphism, of course $\mathbb{Z}_2$ component has to be mapped to $0$. But all of the remaining free generators can be mapped onto an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{Q}$. Making the number of homomorphisms equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Sir, I have one more question.Can this logic be also applied for finding group homomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}^*$ to $\mathbb{Q}$?

@SandeepTiwari no. Non-rational reals cannot be expressed through primes or any other simple numeric structures. In fact $\mathbb{R}^*$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{R}$ through exp and log. So this reduces to finding all homomorphisms from standard $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. Which again there are lots of, since $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I would add to @freakish's comment that the existence of homomorphisms $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb Q$ is quite nuanced and depends on the axiom of choice, so there's probably no way to write down such a homomorphism explicitly.

@freakish #lisyarus Thank you both for your kind reply.
